# Android - Transaction - Task is not yet complete

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I found a few examples of "task not yet complete," but have not found any examples for transactions. I am using a transaction because in my application I need the operation to be able to fail if there is no internet connection. I can detect this with a transaction.

I have a Collection with Documents. I am trying to obtain the names of the documents. Sometimes the code works fine, but majority of the time I get the "task not yet complete" error. The frustrating thing is that I have a callback for "onComplete" so it's weird that the transaction isn't complete when the callback is... called.

I get the "task not yet complete exception in the onCompleteListener(). What's frustrating is that I even check to ensure if (task.isSuccessful() && task.isComplete()). Do I need to use a continuation? If so, please provide an example - I just don't quite understand it yet.

```
// Note: states is an ArrayList<String>
//       snapshot is a QuerySnapshot

public void getStatesList(){

    states.clear(); 
    states.add("Select A State");

    db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) {
            // Collect Snapshot data
            snapshot = db.collection("DATA").get();
            return null;
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful() && task.isComplete()){

                try{
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : snapshot.getResult()){
                        states.add(document.getId());
                    }
                    sendResponseToActivity("Success", RESULT_OK);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); // Transaction is not yet complete
                    sendResponseToActivity("Fail", RESULT_OK);
                }
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            if(e.getMessage().contains("UNAVAILABLE"))
                sendResponseToActivity("NoInternet", RESULT_OK);
            else
                sendResponseToActivity("Fail", RESULT_OK);
        }
    });

} // End getStatesList()
```

Comment: I have now tried changing the type Void to QuerySnapshot and returning that value down to the onCompleteListener (instead of using a global variable: Task<QuerySnapshot> snapshot), using continuation, using a new thread for Task.await(), an so forth. More than likely, I just don't understand continuation enough to figure this one out on my own. Everything I try, I get the error where task.getResult() is.

Comment: For now, I've reprogrammed using a generic (non-transaction) collection.get() call - using a handler that, at 400ms, sends a failure response back to my activity if the data is not retrieved . This handler is required, since the collection.get() call will never fail. I believe the get call is queued up and waits for a connection, which isn't useful until the next run (this is a setup process, so there shouldn't be another run). I need the most up-to-date data anyway, not cached.

Comment: I have started a bounty. Please provide a coding example so I can visually see my mistakes here. Feel free to change the Void to QuerySnapshot as that seems more proper and is what I actually needed in the end to collect document ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you call `db.collection("DATA").get()` but this **doesn't operate inside of the transaction** (that is done using [`transaction.get(docRef)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)), [`transaction.update(docRef, newData)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction#public-transaction-update-documentreference-documentref,-mapstring,-object-data) and so on). Just because the Task of the "transaction" has completed, it doesn't mean that this rogue database call has.

If the purpose is to get the server's copy of `/DATA` and only the server's copy, use [`Query#get(Source source)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#public-taskquerysnapshot-get-source-source) with [`Source.SERVER`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source#public-static-final-source-server). (Note: pending server writes may be merged into the data to reflect the most up-to-date copy of the server's data)

```
public void getStatesList(){
    states.clear();
    states.add("Select A State");

    db.collection("DATA").get(Source.SERVER)
        .addOnSuccessListener(querySnapshot -> {
            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot){
                states.add(document.getId());
            }
            sendResponseToActivity("Success", RESULT_OK);
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(ex -> {
            if (ex.getMessage().contains("UNAVAILABLE")) {
                sendResponseToActivity("NoInternet", RESULT_OK); // RESULT_OK?
            } else {
                sendResponseToActivity("Fail", RESULT_OK); // RESULT_OK?
            }
        });
}
```

However, because the above version uses and modifies global variables, I would implement it using:

```
/** Returns server's list of states */
public Task<ArrayList<String>> getStatesList() {
    return db.collection("DATA").get(Source.SERVER)
        .onSuccessTask(querySnapshot -> {
            ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<>();

            // NOTE: states.add("Select A State"); was removed here
            
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot) {
                states.add(document.getId());
            }

            return Tasks.forResult(states);
        });
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
getStatesList().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        ArrayList<String> states = task.getResult();
        // do something with states, like update UI
        // don't forget that "Select A State" isn't in the array
    } else {
        Exception ex = task.getException();
        if (ex.getMessage().contains("UNAVAILABLE")) {
            // offline, do something
        } else {
            // unexpected error, do something
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! There were two points to this reply that I really needed. First, I wanted data from the server in real-time, which applies to other areas of work for me. Secondly, I am receiving the exception, which gives me an appropriate error message when the connection is non-existent. I also had no idea you could add parameters to .get(). That alone was super helpful.